# Fibonacci Sum of Large Numbers(Only Last Digit to be Printed)

Tags: c++, c, performance, fibonacci

I have been trying to come out with a solution regarding the problem of finding the last digit of the sum of large n Fibonacci series. 
I have been able to pass several test cases with large n. But I'm stuck at the following case where n = 832564823476. I know it can be solved using Pisano's period but I'm unable to come out with a efficient algo. Any help would be great. Thanks.
My code that I have implemented is as follows-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int calc_fib(int n) {

    int fib[n+1];
    fib[0]=0;
    fib[1]=1;
    int res = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i<=n;i++){
        fib[i] = (fib[i-1]%10 + fib[i-2]%10)%10;
        res = res + fib[i];
    }
    return (res%10);
}

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << calc_fib(n) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, how large is `int` on your system? Usually they are 32 bit, meaning that the maximum number is 4.29 billion. Since you use signed ints, you get half of that, 2,14 billion. Are there really negative Fibonacci numbers, why do you need a signed type?

Comment: Further, `n = 832564823476` and you're using a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) `int fib[n+1];` for a sequence you don't even need to persist? I think its safe to assume you don't have that much automatic variable storage (which is ok, since as I said, you don't need to keep all those numbers anyway).

Comment: @codeyourstack, if you used a char instead of int which is 1 byte it would work in theory as you have taken the individual parts of the fib functions modulo 10. However at 1 byte your array would require 1 * 832564823476 bytes or 832 gigabytes. I think a windows nt process gets 4 gigabytes max. As WhozCraig noted you don't need to keep the entire array.

Comment: Also, add `std::cout << n << '\n';` to `main`and have a look at the result.

Comment: @molbdnilo As for the index for the for loop he could fix that by using a string (char[]).

Comment: @marshalcraft No need; 832564823476 needs only 40 bits.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I solved it using Pisano period. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I've rollback to edit the answer out of the question - feel free to accept your own answer when you can (there is a system delay imposed) to show that it has been solved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**SOLVED IT**

Works on all range of inputs. It works on the following algorithm.
The idea is to notice that the last digits of fibonacci numbers also occur in sequences of length 60 (from the previous problem: since pisano peiod of 10 is 60). Irrespective of how large n is, its last digit is going to have appeared somewhere within the sequence.
Two Things apart from edge case of 10 as last digit.

- Sum of nth Fibonacci series = F(n+2) -1
- Then pisano period of module 10 = let n+2 mod (60) = m then find F(m) mod(10)-1

Code as follows;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long calc_fib(long long n) {

    n = (n+2)%60;
    int fib[n+1];
    fib[0]=0;
    fib[1]=1;
    int res = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i<=n;i++){
        fib[i] = (fib[i-1]%10 + fib[i-2]%10)%10;
        // res = res + fib[i];
    }
    // cout<<fib[n]<<"\n";
    if(fib[n] == 0){
        return 9;
    }
    return (fib[n]%10-1);
}

int main() {
    long long n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << calc_fib(n) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Btw, since `int fib[n+1];` fails to allocate the array at run time use `int * fib; fib = new int[n + 1];` (dynamic array) as shown here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic

Comment: And what if n is 10^1000000 ?

Answer (score 6):

Actually it's even easier than Niall answer

```
int get_fibonacci_sum_last_digit(long long n) {
    const int kPisanoSize = 60;
    int rest = n % kPisanoSize;
    int preparedNumbers[kPisanoSize] = {0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 8, 3, 
        2, 6, 9, 6, 6, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 4, 2, 7, 0, 8, 9, 8, 8, 7, 
        6, 4, 1, 6, 8, 5, 4, 0, 5, 6, 2, 9, 2, 2, 5, 8, 4, 3, 8, 2, 1, 
        4, 6, 1, 8, 0, 9, 0};
    return preparedNumbers[rest];
```

}

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to output the last digit as you said, I think you can just make use of the [Pisano Period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) you mentioned, as for modular 10, the cycle length is only 60 and you can just pre-make an array of that 60 digits.

If you want to compute by yourself, I think you can use [Matrix Exponentiation](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms) which gives you `O(lg N)` complexity, when calculating the matrix exponents, keep storing the temporary result modular 10. See the [*Matrices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) section for your reference.

Comment: Solved it using pisano using a different concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your function removing the array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int calc_fib(long long int n) {

    int fibzero = 0;
    int fibone = 1;
    int fibnext;
    long long int res = 1;
    for (long long int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {

        fibnext = (fibone + fibzero) % 10;
        fibzero = fibone;
        fibone = fibnext;
        res = res + fibnext;
    }
    return (res % 10);
}

int main() 
{
    long long int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << calc_fib(n) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: still waiting for it to return.

Comment: if it takes 1 microsecond to compute a single cycle of the for loop then it would take about 9 days to return.

Answer (score 1):

**Last digit of Fibonacci sum repeats after 60 elements.**

Here the period is 60 [0-59].
  So to get the last digit of n'th sum of number is the last digit of n%60'th sum of 
  number

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int get_last_digit(int n){
  std::vector<int> last_digits(60);
  long long a = 0, b = 1;
  last_digits[0] = 0;
  last_digits[1] = 1;
  long long temp, sum = 1;
  // Fill last_digits vector with the first 60 sums last digits
  for (int i = 2; i < 60; i++) {
    temp = a+b;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    sum += temp;
    last_digits[i] = sum%10;
  }
  // Now return n%60'th element
  return last_digits[n%60];
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int n;
  std::cin>>n;
  std::cout << get_last_digit(n);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to solve the problem (I use java). The logic is to utilize the pisano period of 10. To write down the corresponding relationship between Sum(F(n)) = F(n+2) + 1 can help a lot. tip: create a fibonacci sequence alone.

```
private static long getFibonacciSum(long n) {
    n = (n + 2) % 60;
    long[] fib = new long[(int) n + 1];
    long cor;
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        fib[i] = (fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2]) % 10;
    }
    if (fib[(int) n] == 0) cor = 9;
    else cor = fib[(int) n] - 1;
    return cor;
}
```

Comment: As this algorithm was already in the previous accepted answer, your main point seems to apply the modulus 10 only once, point that was already in @marshalcraft answer.  It seems then that your answer only provides a Java implementation. This  seems useful but it isn't then a new answer to the question which was about a better algorithm, i suggest you then to specify as a note in your answer that it is a Java implementation of previous answers.