# code to find last digit of sum of fibonacci sequence in less time

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

I have used the following code to find the last digit of sum of fibonacci numbers

```
#using python3
def fibonacci_sum(n):

    if n < 2: print(n)
    else:
        a, b = 0, 1
        sum=1
        for i in range(1,n):
            a, b = b, (a+b)
            sum=sum+b
    lastdigit=(sum)%10
    print(lastdigit)


n = int(input(""));
fibonacci_sum(n);
```

My code is working fine. But for a larger given input like 613455 it takes much more time. I need an efficient code. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: this smells of some kind of hackerrank / project euler. Several other hits on SO, f.e. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950579/fibonacci-sum-of-large-numbersonly-last-digit-to-be-printed .. also plenty of google hits: https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C1NDCM_deDE736DE736&ei=4KQKW4SGKMO2kwXFmYGwCA&q=last+digit+sum+fibonacci&oq=last+digit+sum+fibonacci&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.12697.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.M6CvLodQLWU - why not chase those?

Comment: You might want to reread  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again. We care about specific problems in code you provide as [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Providing solutions for webpages challenging _you_ is not what we do (although if someone is bored, she might answer non the less)...

Comment: @Patrick Arthur like me... I was bored

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fibonacci Sum of Large Numbers(Only Last Digit to be Printed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950579/fibonacci-sum-of-large-numbersonly-last-digit-to-be-printed)

Answer (score 2):

## Keeping track of the last digit only

Note that whenever you add integers, the last digit of the sum depends only on the last digits of the addents. This means we only have to keep the last digit on every iteration. The same applies to the sum, at all time we only need to keep its last digit.

```
def fibonacci_last_digit_sum(n):
    sum_, a, b = 0, 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b = b, (a + b) % 10
        sum_ = (sum_ + b) % 10
    return sum_


print(fibonacci_last_digit_sum(613455)) # 2
```

## The above yields a cyclic result

Any triple `(a, b, sum_)` entirely defines the next elements in the sequence. But since we are keeping track solely of the last digit, then there are finitely many such triples. This means that the sequence of triples `(a, b, sum_)` must be cyclic, it comes back to the same value at some point. In particular, a gross upper bound for the length of this cycle is `1000`.

This means we can easily check empirically what the length of that cycle is with this updated version of our code.

```
def fibonacci_last_digit_sum(n):
    sum_, a, b = 0, 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b = b, (a + b) % 10
        sum_ = (sum_ + b) % 10
    return a, b, sum_

seen = set()

for x in range(1000):
    triple = fibonacci_last_digit_sum(x)
    if triple in seen:
        print('Back to start:', x)
        break
    seen.add(triple)
```

Output:

```
Back to start: 60
```

In other words, the cycle is of length `60`.

This means for any `n`, the answer will be the same as for `n % 60`. This allows to write a solution which run-time depends only on the modulo operation `n % 60`, [which is *O(log(n))*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320420/time-complexity-of-a-modulo-operation).

```
def fibonacci_last_digit_sum(n):
    sum_, a, b = 0, 0, 1
    for _ in range(n % 60):  # We range over n % 60 instead of n
        a, b = b, (a + b) % 10
        sum_ = (sum_ + b) % 10
    return sum_  

print(fibonacci_last_digit_sum(613455)) # 2
```

One last improvement would be to hardcode the cycle in a list, as it is relatively short, and return the value at index `n % 60`.

Comment: Apart from answering slightly the wrong answer (the question is to return the last digit of the sum of the first n Fibonacci numbers), neither of these methods are good for very large n. I wrote an answer, but there's also a couple of similar answers on the dupe question (which I didn't notice when I wrote my own answer). The best solution is O(1)  and uses the Pisano period.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks for pointing out that I answered the wrong question. Only the "keep track of last digit" is still applicable in that case. It is true your answer is the best approach. I'll update mine to show how someone with no knowledge of the CRT can empirically come to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for code that returns the last digit of the sum of the first n Fibonacci numbers.

First thing to note is that fib(1) + fib(2) + ... + fib(n) = fib(n+2)-1.

That's easily proved: Let S(n) be the sum of the first n Fibonacci numbers. Then S(1) = 1, S(2) = 2, and S(n) - S(n-1) = fib(n). The result follows by induction.

Second, modulo 2, the Fibonacci numbers repeat on a cycle of length 3, and modulo 5, the Fibonacci numbers repeat on a cycle of length 20. [See the wikipedia page on the Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period).

This gives us an O(1) solution using the above and the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

```
f2 = [0,1,1]
f5 = [0,1,1,2,3,0,3,3,1,4,0,4,4,3,2,0,2,2,4,1]

def f1(n):
    y = f5[(n+2) % 20]
    return (y-1)%10 if y%2==f2[(n+2)%3] else y+4

cases = [1, 2, 100, 12334, 1234567]

for i in cases:
    print(i, f1(i))
```